# Faces of the intersection of convex sets

Tags: convex-geometry, convexity

Let $V$ be a normed real vector space and let $K_1, K_2\subseteq V$ be closed convex subsets such that the intersection $K_1\cap K_2$ is non-empty. Assume that $F_1$ is a face of $K_1$ and $F_2$ is a face of $K_2$ (face $F$ of a convex set $K$ is a convex subset such that $a=tb+(1-t)c$, for $a\in F$, $b, c\in K$, $0<t<1$, implies $b,c\in F$). If $F_1\cap F_2$ is non-empty, then it is a face of $K_1\cap K_2$.

> Question: is every face $F$ of $K_1\cap K_2$ the intersection of $F_1, F_2$, where $F_1$ is a face of $K_1$ and $F_2$ is a face of $K_2$?

Probably the answer is known to experts working in convexity, however I am not able to find a reference in the literature. In my opinion the answer is affirmative, but maybe I am wrong and there are (even simple) counterexamples. It is possible that the answer is much simpler if one assumes that $V$ is finite dimensional. On the other hand it is also possible that the answer is known also for more general case when instead of the intersection of two convex sets we have the intersection of an arbitrary family of closed convex sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For finite-dimensional $V$, your definition of a face is equivalent to the definition of a *poonem*, according to part (i) of Exercise 7 on page 21 of the book [Convex Polytopes by B. Gruenbaum](https://archive.org/download/springer_10.1007-978-1-4613-0019-9/10.1007-978-1-4613-0019-9.pdf); then the positive answer to your question is part (iii) of Exercise 9 on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the answer is **Yes**.

In the affine subspace $A$ spanned by $K:=K_1\cap K_2$, a face is the intersection of $K$ with a (closed) supporting hyperplane $\Pi$. By Hahn-Banach, there is an extension $\Pi_1$ of $\Pi$ as a closed hyperplane in $V$, so that $\Pi_1$ is a supporting hyperplane for $K_1$. Then $F_1=\Pi_1\cap K_1$ is a face of $K_1$. Likewise, $\Pi$ extends as a closed supporting hyperplane $\Pi_2$ of $K_2$, and $F_2=\Pi_2\cap K_2$ is a face of $K_2$. Eventually, $F=F_1\cap F_2$.

Comment: I have upvoted the answer. It seems that the reasoning is correct at least for some faces. However it is not clear to me, why a face of $K$ is an intersection of $K$ and a supporting hyperplane. It seems to me that faces with this property are exposed faces. What if $F$ is a face of $K$ which is not exposed?

Comment: Indeed Denis Serre is referring to exposed faces, while the question was about faces, which is a more general definition. More about these two notions with examples/counterexamples can be found in Convex Analysis and Minimization Algorithms I, by J.B. Hirriart-Hurruty and C. Lemaréchal.